# How to get actual Google search URL in Excel + How to extract website adress out of cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am stuck at the current situation. I have a couple of hundreds business names of which i have to search for the website adress.

**Question 1:**

What i have at the moment is an google search link in excel with the =hyperlink(etc,etc), with the business name and adress.

For example: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=Airbus+12th street 12 +New York+&btnG=Google+Search"

But what i actually need is the url in the internet browser, which i get when i click on the excel hyperlink:

If i click on above link, this is the actual link i need: https://www.google.nl/search?hl=en&q=Airbus+12th+street+%C2%A012%C2%A0+New+York+&btnG=Google+Search&gws_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=o3nLWqbjN87PwAKY54_oCg

My question, is it possible to do this automaticly and get the actual link in excel ?

**Question 2:** 
In excel i have a whole cell full of data. In this data, there is 1 url. For example, cell contains: ''ujeri sfifs93 sfisdsu fiweu2 732732 fjsdfue http:www.iwantthislink.comm sdfsdf shsdf sju32u3un''

is is possible to automaticly extract a word from this cell, beginning with http://www. ? And do this for every cell i want ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, for every question, you should create separate questions.

Answer (score 0):

Example for your first question. You could do this by navigating to the url you've got in your workbook, wait for the redirect then return the redirected url

```
Public Sub GetRedirectedLink()
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim InitialUrl As String, RedirectUrl As String

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    InitialUrl = "http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=Airbus+12th%20street%2012+New%20York+&btnG=Google+Search"

    With IE
        .Visible = False
        ' Navigate to url
        .navigate InitialUrl

        ' Wait while page loads
        Do While .Busy
            Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Loop

        ' return Redirected URL
        RedirectUrl = .LocationURL
    End With

    MsgBox RedirectUrl
End Sub
```

For your second question you could use regular expressions to return the domain name (if that is the part that you want)